# Ansible set dictionary value based on another variable value

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

How can I implement below condition, to set value of dictionary `config` in Ansible ?
Dictionary `config` and variable `turn_on_encryption` are both specified in same vars file.

if `turn_on_encryption == true`, then:

```
  config:
    path: /var/www/html
    cert_path: /path/to/certificate
    protocol: https
```

else:

```
  config:
    path: /var/www/html
    cert_path: ""
    protocol: http
```

Is this possible with Ansible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like below, using the if else in `jinja2` :

```
  vars:
    config:
      path: /var/www/html
      cert_path: "{{ '/path/to/certificate' if turn_on_encryption else '' }}"
      protocol: "{{ 'htpps' if turn_on_encryption else 'http' }}"
```

you could use too the ternary filter jinja2: [ternary sample](https://chuckyz.wordpress.com/2016/11/21/advancing-in-ansible-ternary-jinja2-filter/)